# runit: unable to lock supervise error on debian

Tags: logging, debian, runit

I'm trying to set up runit and logging on my debian wheezy VM. So far I've managed to get gunicorn service to start by following this setup:

```
sudo mkdir /etc/sv/gunicorn
sudo vi /etc/sv/gunicorn/run
sudo ln -s /etc/sv/gunicorn/run /etc/service
```

My log run file has:

```
LOG_DIR=/home/$USER/logs/gunicorn/

exec svlogd -tt $LOG_DIR
```

When I run **sudo runsvdir /etc/service/gunicorn**

```
runsv supervise: fatal: unable to lock supervise/lock: temporary failure
```

No idea what I'm doing wrong, any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the previous process has shut down completely? You may need to find and remove a .lock or .pid file that tells the system that it is in use by another process

Answer (score 4):

In `ls -la /etc/service/gunicorn/supervise` i didn't see a `.lock` but there was a `lock` file. Removing that lock file caused a bit of mayhem.

Thus i got rid of the symlink; killed the pids in `ps aux | grep gunicorn` and re symlinked. May be the ultimate end, but does get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

This can be caused by the `runit` daemon being stopped while it's individual services are still running.

Instead of deleting & re-creating `symlinks` for the `runit` service:

```
sv stop myservice
rm /etc/sv/myservice/supervise/lock
sv start myservice # or start the runit service
```

In your particular case  your `symlink` was incorrect & should be:

```
ln -s /etc/sv/gunicorn /etc/service/gunicorn
```

You should be symlinking the `sv` directory not the `run` file into `/etc/service/myservice`